# RAD/Eclipse Eclipse Test and Performance Tools Platform, export data to text file

Tags: java, eclipse, report, rad

I am using the RAD (also on Eclipse) Test and Performance Monitoring.  I monitor CPU performance time with it, on particular methods, etc.

It is a good tool for my monitoring my applications but I can't copy/paste or export the output to a text file format.  So I can send to the others.

There has to be a way to export this?

Also, I can save the output to file but it is '*.trcxml' binary file?

has anyone seen a parser for this file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone with RAD installed can view the .trcxml file by going to `File` > `Import` > `Profiling and Logging` > `Profiling File`.  From here, you can use the filters to select ranges or "show all", and you should be able to copy/paste or convert into whatever format you like.

If you would rather have the file generated as XML instead of binary, you can use the optional `TPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT` environment variable.  Simply set `TPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT=xml`.

Edited based on feedback from poster:  If you use the environment variable, TPTP ouputs the file as zipped xml, but does not change the file extension.  So, you will need to rename the resulting .trcxml file to .zip.

Comment: " From here, you can use the filters to select ranges or "show all", and you should be able to copy/paste or convert into whatever format you like."

I will try both suggestions.

Where do you set the environment variable?:

"you can use the optional TPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT environment variable"

Comment: This is a system-wide environment variable.  If you're using a unix variant, this is typically done with env or via ~/.bash_profile (but varies from shell to shell).  If you're using Windows, check this for a brief description of how to set an environment variable: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519. In Windows, the variable name will be "TPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT", and the variable value will be "xml" (no quotes, and there is no equals sign).

Comment: I gave you the answer but most methods did not work.  It looked like the right idea though:

1. Import Profile File did not give me any chance to copy paste.  There is only the tabular interface with the method/class names and the time.  But I can't copy paste.  Could you provide a screenshot if you have.

2. I tried the TPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT on both the environment variables on Windows and as a jvm arg/setting, did not work.

Eclipse/Rad version 3.4.2 Windows XP

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work.  My answer was based on my notes from a project in Jan '09 (using linux), so it's possible that my info doesn't apply to your version/OS.  I no longer have a copy of RAD, but I see that they have a free trial available -- I'll give it a whirl tonight and let you know what I find.

Comment: Thanks.  And I bet this would work with Eclipse 3.4+.  I think the TPTP application is the same for Rad and Eclipse.

I think the best bet it is to see if the XML output works.  There is probably a -DTPTP_OUTPUT_FORMAT=xml something I am missing.

Comment: OK, Cool, it is a zipped XML format. I changed the filename to .zip and was able to read the file.

Thanks.

Comment: Berlin -- glad you figured it out, sorry I wasn't more help.